# TableElement.append(Element) adding row out of order

Tags: dart, dart-html

I'm doing a simple iteration of data to create TableRowElements that I add to a TableElement:

```dart
TableRowElement table_header = new TableRowElement();
transactions_table.append(table_header);
...

var incomes = new Set();

...
if(amount > 0 && !incomes.contains(data_item))
{
    TableRowElement item_row = new TableRowElement();
    item_row.addCell().text = item_name;
    incomes.add(item_row);
}
...

incomes.forEach((row)
{
  transactions_table.append(row);
});

transactions_table.appendHtml("<tr><td colspan=${col_count+1}>--</td></tr>  ");

expenses.forEach((row)
{
  transactions_table.append(row);
});
```

This produces the following result:

```dart
                 Jun         Jul        Aug         Sep     Oct
--
rent             1,350.00   1,350.00                830.00  1,350.00
carpet cleaning                         -125.00
```

Appending the spacer row after the `forEach` iterations puts it at the bottom of the table.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Can you please add the generated HTML?

Comment: Fun fact: you can do `expenses.forEach(transaction_table.append)` because forEach just takes a function.

Comment: forEach shouldn't be async. Thus the above code looks good! To solve the problem we need more information.

Comment: I did a simple example to replicate, and of course it works :-P.  However--  I found the change that causes the above weirdity in the code:  I use a Set instead of a List, the line `if(amount > 0 && !incomes.contains(item_row))` (web/propmgmt.dart:102).  If I remove the `!contains`, things work, but I don't know why.  I've upped the code to https://github.com/chambery/PropMgmt.git if anyone would care to take a look.

Answer (score 1):

Try simplifying the code you're running to some hard-coded values to understand what's going. I believe what you're trying should work fine; I just executed the following in [Try Dart](https://try.dartlang.org/) and it worked as expected:

```dart
import 'dart:html';

main() {
var transactions_table = new TableElement();

var incomes = new Set();
var expenses = new Set();

var item_row = new TableRowElement();
item_row.addCell().text = "Danny";
incomes.add(item_row);

var item_row2 = new TableRowElement();
item_row2.addCell().text = "Danny2";
expenses.add(item_row2);

incomes.forEach(transactions_table.append);
transactions_table.appendHtml("<tr><td colspan=2>--</td></tr>  ");
expenses.forEach(transactions_table.append);

document.body.append(transactions_table);
}
```

It's worth checking the HTML being output; because browsers will often render table content in the wrong place if the markup is incorrect.